# What is the csh/tcsh equivalent of set -u in bash?

Tags: csh, tcsh

csh/tcsh by default exits with error on undefined variables. I want to suppress that behavior for a piece of code just like bash does with `set +u`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no setting for this.

The best you can do is check if the variable exists with `$?varname`:

```
if ( $?undefined ) then
    echo "$undefined"
endif
```

Or use `if ( ! $?undefined )` to inverse the check.